# Many-to-many relationship inside a symfony 3 form

Tags: many-to-many, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a problem implementing a symfony 3 form with two objects having a many-to-many relationship.

I have two datatables, "Users" and "Roles". I want to have a form, where I can edit a user and assign a user some roles. In detail I want a form where each Role is a checkbox and I can choose which role a user has. 
I know, that I have to implement a new UserType,, but how can I implement the dynamic checkboxes?

This is my User-Class:

```
<?php

// src/AppBundle/Entity/User.php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
* @ORM\Table(name="app_users")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
*/
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    private $id;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, unique=true)
    */
    private $username;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
    */
    private $password;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60, unique=true)
    */
    private $email;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
    */
    private $isActive;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role", inversedBy="users")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_roles")
     */
    private $roles;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->isActive = true;
        // may not be needed, see section on salt below
        // $this->salt = md5(uniqid(null, true));
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function getSalt()
    {
        // you *may* need a real salt depending on your encoder
        // see section on salt below
        return null;
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        $permissionsArray = array();
        foreach ($this->roles as $role)
        {
            $rolesPermissions = $role->getPermissions();
            for($i=0;$i<count($rolesPermissions);$i++)
                if(!in_array($rolesPermissions[$i],$permissionsArray))
                    $permissionsArray[] = $rolesPermissions[$i];
        }
        return $permissionsArray;
    }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            // see section on salt below
            // $this->salt,
        ));
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
        $this->id,
        $this->username,
        $this->password,
        // see section on salt below
        // $this->salt
        ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set username
     *
     * @param string $username
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set isActive
     *
     * @param boolean $isActive
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setIsActive($isActive)
    {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isActive
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getIsActive()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }
}
```

And this is my Role-Class:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Role
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="role")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\RoleRepository")
 */
class Role
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="bezeichnung", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $bezeichnung;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="roles")
     */
    private $users;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Permission", inversedBy="roles")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="roles_permissions")
     */
    private $permissions;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set bezeichnung
     *
     * @param string $description
     *
     * @return Role
     */
    public function setBezeichnung($bezeichnung)
    {
        $this->bezeichnung = $bezeichnung;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get bezeichnung
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBezeichnung()
    {
        return $this->bezeichnung;
    }
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->users = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->roles = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add user
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\User $user
     *
     * @return Role
     */
    public function addUser(\AppBundle\Entity\User $user)
    {
        $this->users[] = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove user
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\User $user
     */
    public function removeUser(\AppBundle\Entity\User $user)
    {
        $this->users->removeElement($user);
    }

    /**
     * Get users
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getUsers()
    {
        return $this->users;
    }


    /**
     * Add permission
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Permission $permission
     *
     * @return Role
     */
    public function addPermission(\AppBundle\Entity\Permission $permission)
    {
        $this->permissions[] = $permission;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove permission
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Permission $permission
     */
    public function removePermission(\AppBundle\Entity\Permission $permission)
    {
        $this->permissions->removeElement($permission);
    }

    /**
     * Get permissions
     *
     * @return Array
     */
    public function getPermissions()
    {
        $permissionsArray = array();
        foreach ($this->permissions as $permission)
            $permissionsArray[] = "ROLE_".$permission->getTechBezeichnung();
        return $permissionsArray;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a) Give your entities a [__toString()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) method.

b) Make a UserType. You can also Use the CLI command `bin/console doctrine:generate:crud` and choose at "write actions" [yes].
The script wil generate a controller, a formType and some templates.

c) add this use statement at the top of UserType:

```
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
```

d) add this formfield into your UserType:

```
->add('roles', EntityType::class, array(
    'expanded => true,
    'multiple' => true
))
```

Comment: Hi, I think this works fine. But now i get a  `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`, because I modified the getRoles and getPermissions (I need to get all the Strings there for autorization). Do you know how I can solve this problem? I need the roles to check in twig-templates with isGranted("ROLE_..."), so the getRoles and getPermissions have to return the string-arrays. Is there a way to handle this?

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() sais that you do not deliver an array. Could the value be null instead?